# Where is the nodeos handling push_transactions from cleos?

Tags: cleos, nodeos, transactions, plugin, net-plugin

I am studying the source code of eos and I saw that in the cleos it has this function.

```
call(push_txn_func, packed_transaction(trx, compression));
```

I think this is used to push the transaction to the chain. So there must be somewhere in the nodeos to handle this transaction from cleos. I spent several days on it searching for that place. 
At first, I saw this function in net_plugin.

```
void handle_message( connection_ptr c, const packed_transaction &msg);
```

But I added logs there and found it's not the place. Then I found

```
void chain_plugin::accept_transaction(const chain::packed_transaction& trx, next_function<chain::transaction_trace_ptr> next) {
my->incoming_transaction_async_method(std::make_shared<packed_transaction>(trx), false, std::forward<decltype(next)>(next));}
```

in the chain_plugin. Again, no log output there. So it may not be the place. So my question is where is the place that nodeos handling the transaction from cleos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is right to find the answer of push_transaction by print logs,but the place is wrong.when we used command cleos push_transaction which call push_txn_func in cleos main.cpp,a better way to find this is:

1、find command in ../../cleos/main.cpp such as **push_transaction**

```
auto trx_result = call(push_txn_func, packed_transaction(trx, packed_transaction::none));
```

2、get the bind funtion in ../../cleos/httpc.hpp like this

```
const string push_txn_func = chain_func_base + "/push_transaction";
```

3、so we can get the info that this funtion located in chain_plugin,then we open chain_plugin.cpp we can find this funtion

```
void read_write::push_transaction(const read_write::push_transaction_params& params, next_function<read_write::push_transaction_results> next) {

   try {
      auto pretty_input = std::make_shared<packed_transaction>();
      auto resolver = make_resolver(this, abi_serializer_max_time);
      try {
         abi_serializer::from_variant(params, *pretty_input, resolver, abi_serializer_max_time);
      } EOS_RETHROW_EXCEPTIONS(chain::packed_transaction_type_exception, "Invalid packed transaction")

      app().get_method<incoming::methods::transaction_async>()(pretty_input, true, [this, next](const fc::static_variant<fc::exception_ptr, transaction_trace_ptr>& result) -> void{
         if (result.contains<fc::exception_ptr>()) {
            next(result.get<fc::exception_ptr>());
         } else {
            auto trx_trace_ptr = result.get<transaction_trace_ptr>();

            try {
               fc::variant pretty_output;
               pretty_output = db.to_variant_with_abi(*trx_trace_ptr, abi_serializer_max_time);

               chain::transaction_id_type id = trx_trace_ptr->id;
               next(read_write::push_transaction_results{id, pretty_output});
            } CATCH_AND_CALL(next);
         }
      });


   } catch ( boost::interprocess::bad_alloc& ) {
      raise(SIGUSR1);
   } CATCH_AND_CALL(next);
}
```

4、after find this funtion and add logs and use cleos command we can find nodeos print your log info.

Comment: You are right. Thanks, I managed to print the log.

Comment: As an eos fans in Hangzhou too,we can.communicate through wechat

Comment: Cool. I bet you are in that wechat group started by eosiofans.